# Approximate inverse of a function with a gamma function

Tags: approximation, gamma-function

I want to find the inverse function of the following expression.(range is a positive real number) I tried to find an approximate expression using series expansion, but it was not easy. How do I get a nice approximate inverse function?

$$\frac{Γ(1 +\frac{1}{k})^2}{Γ(1 +\frac{2}{k})}$$

Answer (score 5):

You want to solve for $k$ the equation
$$y=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{k}\right)^2}{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{k}\right)}\tag 1$$

There no formal series for $\Gamma (1+\epsilon )$ around $\epsilon=0$. However
$$\log (\Gamma (1+\epsilon))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{\psi ^{(n-1)}(1)}{n! }\, \epsilon^n$$ Taking logarithms of both sides, expanding the series and transforming into one of   the simplest Padé approximants, gives, after simplifications , the quadratic equation
$$k^2+\frac{12 \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}k+\frac{1}{6} \pi ^2 \left(\frac{1}{\log (y)}+\frac{864 \zeta (3)^2}{\pi^6}-\frac{7}{5}\right)=0$$  that is to say
$$\color{red}{\large k\sim-\frac{6 \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}+\sqrt{\frac{7 \pi ^2}{30}-\frac{\pi ^2}{6 \log (y)}-\frac{108 \zeta (3)^2}{\pi ^4}}}$$

Notice that the error associated to the used $[2,2]$  Padé approximant is
$$\frac{-14 \pi ^6 \zeta (3)+4320 \zeta (3)^3+90 \pi ^4 \zeta (5)}{15 \pi ^4 k^5} \sim  \frac{0.284}{k^5}$$
Below is a very detailed table when applying this formula for all the range of $y$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
y & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1000 & 0.45888 &  0.41134 \\
 0.2000 & 0.58184 &  0.54269 \\
 0.3000 & 0.70698 &  0.67416 \\
 0.4000 & 0.84913 &  0.82171 \\
 0.5000 & 1.02252 &  1.00000 \\
 0.6000 & 1.24939 &  1.23147 \\
 0.7000 & 1.57417 &  1.56069 \\
 0.8000 & 2.11045 &  2.10135 \\
 0.9000 & 3.30821 &  3.30352 \\
& & \\
 0.9100 & 3.52864 &  3.52441 \\
 0.9200 & 3.78904 &  3.78526 \\
 0.9300 & 4.10323 &  4.09991 \\
 0.9400 & 4.49279 &  4.48992 \\
 0.9500 & 4.99375 &  4.99134 \\
 0.9600 & 5.67206 &  5.67012 \\
 0.9700 & 6.66554 &  6.66408 \\
 0.9800 & 8.33137 &  8.33038 \\
 0.9900 & 12.0899 &  12.0894 \\
& & \\
 0.9910 & 12.7840 &  12.7835 \\
 0.9920 & 13.6043 &  13.6039 \\
 0.9930 & 14.5946 &  14.5943 \\
 0.9940 & 15.8232 &  15.8229 \\
 0.9950 & 17.4039 &  17.4036 \\
 0.9960 & 19.5451 &  19.5449 \\
 0.9970 & 22.6827 &  22.6825 \\
 0.9980 & 27.9458 &  27.9457 \\
 0.9990 & 39.8255 &  39.8255 \\
& & \\
 0.9991 & 42.0195 &  42.0194 \\
 0.9992 & 44.6129 &  44.6128 \\
 0.9993 & 47.7438 &  47.7438 \\
 0.9994 & 51.6280 &  51.6279 \\
 0.9995 & 56.6255 &  56.6255 \\
 0.9996 & 63.3958 &  63.3958 \\
 0.9997 & 73.3165 &  73.3164 \\
 0.9998 & 89.9585 &  89.9585 \\
 0.9999 & 127.524 &  127.524
\end{array}
\right)$$

This gives for the asymptotics
$$\color{blue}{\large k=-\frac{6 \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}+\frac{\pi }{ \sqrt{6(1-y)}}+ \left(\frac{3 \pi }{40}-\frac{54 \zeta (3)^2}{\pi ^5}\right)\sqrt{6(1-y)}+O\left((1-y)^{3/2}\right)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. This answer has helped me a lot in developing my thinking. thank you.

Comment: @HeeRyangChoi. The second answer is much better than the first. And you are welcome. It is a very interesting problem I am trying to generalize. Notice that three users asked to reopen the post. Cheers :-)

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I tried reopening, but I don't know if it's working properly. I hope you have fun with math. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

*I prefer to add a second answer.*

Let $x=\frac 1k$ and $z=\log(y)$ and expand again
$$z=\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} a_n\,x^n$$ the first $a_n$ being
$$\left\{\frac{\pi ^2}{6},2 \zeta (3),\frac{7 \pi ^4}{180},6 \zeta (5),\frac{31 \pi
   ^6}{2835},18 \zeta (7),\frac{127 \pi ^8}{37800},\frac{170 }{3}\zeta (9),\frac{73
   \pi ^{10}}{66825},186 \zeta (11),\cdots\right\}$$

Using series reversion
$$\color{red}{\large\frac 1 k=x=t+\frac{a_3 }{2 a_2}t^2+\frac{5 a_3^2-4 a_2 a_4 }{8
   a_2^2}t^3+\frac{2 a_3^3-3 a_2 a_3 a_4+a_2^2 a_5 }{2
   a_2^3}t^4+O(t^5)}$$ where $\color{red}{t=\sqrt{-\frac{z}{a_2}}=\frac 1 \pi \sqrt{-6\log(y)}}$

Repeating the same calculations,as shown below, the results are significantly much better (notice that still better could be done adding the next powers of $t$; not done here because the next coefficient is too long to be typed here).

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
y & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.1000 & 0.40978 &  0.41134 \\
 0.2000 & 0.54120 &  0.54269 \\
 0.3000 & 0.67282 &  0.67416 \\
 0.4000 & 0.82056 &  0.82171 \\
 0.5000 & 0.99904 &  1.00000 \\
 0.6000 & 1.23071 &  1.23147 \\
 0.7000 & 1.56014 &  1.56069 \\
 0.8000 & 2.10101 &  2.10135 \\
 0.9000 & 3.30338 &  3.30352 \\
 & & \\
 0.9100 & 3.52428 &  3.52441 \\
 0.9200 & 3.78515 &  3.78526 \\
 0.9300 & 4.09981 &  4.09991 \\
 0.9400 & 4.48984 &  4.48992 \\
 0.9500 & 4.99128 &  4.99134 \\
 0.9600 & 5.67008 &  5.67012 \\
 0.9700 & 6.66405 &  6.66408 \\
 0.9800 & 8.33037 &  8.33038 \\
 0.9900 & 12.0894 &  12.0894 \\
 & & \\
 0.9910 & 12.7835 &  12.7835 \\
 0.9920 & 13.6039 &  13.6039 \\
 0.9930 & 14.5943 &  14.5943 \\
 0.9940 & 15.8229 &  15.8229 \\
 0.9950 & 17.4036 &  17.4036 \\
 0.9960 & 19.5449 &  19.5449 \\
 0.9970 & 22.6825 &  22.6825 \\
 0.9980 & 27.9457 &  27.9457 \\
 0.9990 & 39.8255 &  39.8255 \\
 & & \\
 0.9991 & 42.0194 &  42.0194 \\
 0.9992 & 44.6128 &  44.6128 \\
 0.9993 & 47.7438 &  47.7438 \\
 0.9994 & 51.6279 &  51.6279 \\
 0.9995 & 56.6255 &  56.6255 \\
 0.9996 & 63.3958 &  63.3958 \\
 0.9997 & 73.3164 &  73.3164 \\
 0.9998 & 89.9585 &  89.9585 \\
 0.9999 & 127.524 &  127.524
\end{array}
\right)$$