# Approximate inverse of $[\Gamma (1+x)]^a=y \,\Gamma (1+ax)$

Tags: taylor-expansion, approximation, gamma-function, inverse-function

Motivated by [this now closed question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4493967/approximate-inverse-of-a-function-with-a-gamma-function),  *just for the  art for art's sake*, I wondered how efficiently we could *approximate* the inverse the function
$$y=\frac{\big[\Gamma (1+x)\big]^a}{\Gamma (1+a x)}\qquad \text{with} \qquad 0 <y <1\qquad \text{and} \qquad a>1~~(a\in R)$$ Taking logarithms and using
$$\log\big[\Gamma (1+\epsilon)\big]=-\gamma\, \epsilon +\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{\zeta(n)}{n}\, \epsilon^n$$ we have

$$-\log(y) =a\sum_{n=2}^\infty (-1)^{n} \,\frac{\zeta (n)}{n}\, (a^{n-1}-1)\, x^n$$
$$\color{red}{z}=\color{red}{-\frac{12 \log (y)}{\pi ^2 (a-1) a}}=x^2-\frac{4 (a+1) \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}x^3+\frac{(a^2+a+1)\pi^2}{30}  x^4-\frac{12 (a+1) \left(a^2+1\right) \zeta (5)}{5 \pi ^2}x^5+O\left(x^6\right)$$

Series reversion gives
$$\color{blue}{x=z^{\frac 12}+\frac{2 (a+1)  \zeta (3)}{\pi ^2}z+\left(\frac{10 (a+1)^2 \zeta (3)^2}{\pi ^4}-\frac{(a^2+a+1)\pi ^2}{60}    \right)z^{\frac 32}+O(z^2)}$$

Some results for $a=\pi$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
y & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 1.377403 &  1.359878 \\
 0.10 & 1.129186 &  1.118798 \\
 0.15 & 0.979501 &  0.972441 \\
 0.20 & 0.870317 &  0.865233 \\
 0.25 & 0.783314 &  0.779542 \\
 0.30 & 0.710272 &  0.707427 \\
 0.35 & 0.646767 &  0.644604 \\
 0.40 & 0.590124 &  0.588477 \\
 0.45 & 0.538587 &  0.537336 \\
 0.50 & 0.490918 &  0.489976 \\
 0.55 & 0.446195 &  0.445495 \\
 0.60 & 0.403684 &  0.403173 \\
 0.65 & 0.362757 &  0.362394 \\
 0.70 & 0.322831 &  0.322582 \\
 0.75 & 0.283299 &  0.283137 \\
 0.80 & 0.243435 &  0.243337 \\
 0.85 & 0.202211 &  0.202159 \\
 0.90 & 0.157825 &  0.157803 \\
 0.95 & 0.105843 &  0.105838
\end{array}
\right)$$

which looks to be quite decent. In fact, it is better than the first iterate of Halley method with $x_0=\sqrt z$.

**My question is**

- Beside adding more terms to the expansion, will there be any other possible approach (independently of the accuracy) ?

Comment: [This Stirling approximation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28sqrt%282+pi+x%29%28x%2Fe%29%5Ex%29%5Ea%2F%28sqrt%282+pi+a+x%29%28a+x%2Fe%29%5E%28%28a+x%29%29%29-+x%21%5Ea%2F%28a+x%29%21%2Ca%3D2) simplifies for integer $a$. Your equation is also $\frac{x!^a}{(ax)!}=y$